# minted: How to pass LaTeX commands via \newminted and how to use different styles?

Tags: minted, sweave

I would like to use `minted` to redefine the Sweave environments `Sinput` and `Soutput` (see the example below). This way, I can have `minted` format my `R` code. There are two problems left:

1) Is it possible to pass other commands (such as `\par` or `\vspace`) to `Sinput` and `Soutput` via minted? As you can see, I tried it for `Soutput` but it failed. It would be great to be able to pass commands/arguments, since that would allow one to adjust the spacing between the `Sinput` and `Soutput` environments. Note: this works with `listings`'s `lstnewenvironment`.

2) Is it possible to use different minted highlighting styles (e.g., `emacs` and `bw`) for `Sinput` and `Soutput` defined below? This way, the input and output could be colorized differently which would be very nice. Note: this works with `listings`'s `\lstset` command which can be used to adjust style-related settings.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{minted}

\xdefinecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\xdefinecolor{semilightgray}{RGB}{235, 235, 235}

\renewenvironment{Schunk}{\par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}}{\\[-0.5\baselineskip]}

\expandafter\let\csname Sinput\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endSinput\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname Soutput\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endSoutput\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname Sinput*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endSinput*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname Soutput*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endSoutput*\endcsname\relax

\usemintedstyle{emacs}

% redefine Sweave's Sinput
\newminted[Sinput]{r}{%
  linenos,% line numbers
  bgcolor=semilightgray% background color
}
% redefine Sweave's Soutput
\newminted[Soutput]{r}{%
  bgcolor=lightgray% background color
%  \protect\vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
<<label=preliminaries, echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
options(width=74, useFancyQuotes="UTF-8", prompt="> ", continue="  ")
options(SweaveHooks=list(fig=function() par(mar=c(4, 4, 0.4, 0.7))))
@
Just before the Schunk, to see the spacing.
<<foo>>=
(x <- rnorm(20))
3!=4
@
Just after the Schunk, to see the spacing.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using my [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package, which uses the same Pygments highlighting library that `minted` does.  I don't use Sweave, so this is just an example of how to get the `Sinput` and `Soutput` to do what you want; it's not a real Sweave document.

I've set `Sinput` to use the `rconsole` lexer, with `emacs` style, and `Soutput` to use the `text` lexer, with `bw` style.  All of this is easy to change.  You should be able to get whatever spacing you want by changing the `Schunk`, `Sinput`, and `Soutput` environments, either by hard-coding spaces, or by adding optional arguments that will produce spaces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\xdefinecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\xdefinecolor{semilightgray}{RGB}{235, 235, 235}

\newenvironment{Schunk}{\vspace{10pt}}{\vspace{10pt}}

\newenvironment{Sinput}{%
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=semilightgray]%
    \begin{pygments}{rconsole}}{\end{pygments}\end{mdframed}\vspace{10pt}}
\setpygmentspygopt{rconsole}{style=emacs}
\newenvironment{Soutput}{%
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]%
    \begin{pygments}{text}}{\end{pygments}\end{mdframed}}
\setpygmentspygopt{text}{style=bw}


\begin{document}
Just before the Schunk, to see the spacing.  
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> 2 + 2
\end{Sinput}

\begin{Soutput}
[1] 4
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
Just after the Schunk, to see the spacing.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. On the one hand, that solves the problem. On the other hand, one has to add line numbers etc. by hand. More importantly, PythonTeX is not included in TeXLive (as far as I know), so will not be available to users by default, which is a disadvantage if you distribute the code.

Comment: The Pygments commands take `fancyvrb` optional arguments, so getting line numbers is just a matter of using `\begin{pygments}[numbers=left,firstnumber=last]{rconsole}`, etc.  Regarding TeX Live, right now PythonTeX is only on GitHub since it's been in beta, but I will add it to CTAN as soon as that's over.  That should be by the end of December.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great to hear that `PythonTeX` will be on CTAN then. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Hmmm... I just realized that this is similar to `Sweave` in that it complicates matters quite a bit (concerning compilation, compatibility etc.). Then `knitr` would also be an option.

Comment: @MariusHofert I just got a few minutes to look at your problem, and a quick answer by `knitr` is provided below.

Comment: @MariusHofert You might try @Yihui's `knitr` example with highlighting from `pythontex`. Compiling the .tex output would be more complicated (for example, pdflatex, pythontex2.py, pdflatex). But if you are using many `Sinput` and `Soutput` environments, you might see a significant speed improvement. `minted` tends to be faster for only a few uses, but slows down rapidly with more; `pythontex` is slowed by the second pdflatex run, but additional uses hardly take more time (40 simple uses for me: `minted`, 12 s; `pythontex`, 3.5 s).  By the way, `pythontex` should be on CTAN in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the comments, this problem can be easily solved by `knitr`, and you do not have to use `Sweave.sty` -- feel free to redefine `Schunk`, `Sinput` and `Soutput`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\xdefinecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\xdefinecolor{semilightgray}{RGB}{235, 235, 235}

\usemintedstyle{emacs}

\newenvironment{Schunk}{\par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}}{\\[-0.5\baselineskip]}
% define Sinput
\newminted[Sinput]{r}{%
  linenos,% line numbers
  bgcolor=semilightgray% background color
}
% define Soutput
\newminted[Soutput]{r}{%
  bgcolor=lightgray% background color
%  \protect\vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
<<label=preliminaries, echo=FALSE, results='hide'>>=
options(width=74, useFancyQuotes="UTF-8")
knit_hooks$set(fig.keep=function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before) par(mar=c(4, 4, 0.4, 0.7))
})
render_sweave()
set_header(highlight = '')
@
Just before the Schunk, to see the spacing.
<<foo>>=
(x <- rnorm(20))
3!=4
@
Just after the Schunk, to see the spacing.
\end{document}
```